# How to not import a new POD file every time I want to create a CC3MeshNode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cocos3d

In cocos3d I would like to duplicate, say a CC3MeshNode of a spinning earth coming from a .POD file (earth.pod). This is how i make 1:

```
[self addContentFromPODFile: @"earth.pod"];

CC3MeshNode* earth = (CC3MeshNode*)[self getNodeNamed: @"Sphere"];
[earth setRotation:cc3v(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)];
CCActionInterval* rotate = [CC3RotateBy actionWithDuration: 1.0
                                                       rotateBy: cc3v(0.0, 30.0, 5.0)];
[earth runAction: [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction: rotate]];
earth.location = cc3v(0, 0, 0);
```

Now I want to create a second earth:

```
CC3MeshNode* earth2 = (CC3MeshNode*)[self getNodeNamed: @"Sphere"];
[earth2 setRotation:cc3v(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)];
CCActionInterval* rotate2 = [CC3RotateBy actionWithDuration: 1.0
                                                       rotateBy: cc3v(0.0, 30.0, 5.0)];
[earth runAction: [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction: rotate2]];
earth2.location = cc3v(5, 0, 0);
```

But this gets rid of the original. How do I create a CC3MeshNode from a POD file which I can duplicate?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

CC3MeshNode* earth2 = [(CC3MeshNode*)[self getNodeNamed: @"Sphere"] copyAutoreleased];

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like:

```
CC3PODResourceNode *resourceNode = [CC3PODResourceNode nodeFromFile: @"earth.pod"];
CC3MeshNode *meshNode1 = [resourceNode getMeshNodeNamed: @"Sphere"];
CC3MeshNode *meshNode2 = [meshNode1 copyWithName: @"Sphere2"];
```